# Trying to parse a RESTful api response

Tags: c#, .net, json, api

I have a problem, and I can't seem to find any clue on google about how to solve it. Im trying to parse the response of a RESTful-api service.

```
[{"account_id":"5401585","history":"84967869|2|03\/30\/2012,84972342|2|03\/30\/2012,85312563|2|04\/02\/2      012,85314831|2|04\/02\/2012,85318847|2|04\/02\/2012,85435388|2|04\/03\/2012,100244102|2|09\/09\/2012,100     245865|2|09\/09\/2012,100249440|2|09\/09\/2012,100251434|2|09\/09\/2012"}]'
```

I don't understand how I can have this response put to a List as my model says.

Basically, I want every line which is divided by the "," added to a list.

My code looks like this:

```
    public class MatchHistoryParser
      {
       public RootObject get()
       {
        using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {

            string URL2 =       @"api url";
            var json = webClient.DownloadString(URL2);
            RootObject match = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

            return match;
        }
    }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public string account_id { get; set; }
    public string history { get; set; }
    public string win_loss_history { get; set; }
}
```

Throws error:"
Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'HoNEnemy.BL.RootObject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly."

Comment: You need a JSON Parser like JSON.NET http://james.newtonking.com/json or the one built into Microsoft. Or generate C# from the JSON to get a feel for what that JSON is: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: The contents of that string is opaque to JavaScript. Once you are inside a string, it's an ad hoc format. (by that mean the history)

Comment: The history should be a string. public class RootObject
{
    public string account_id { get; set; }
    public string history { get; set; }
}

Comment: What if I want to iterate through the history?

Comment: myObject.History.Split(" ").ToList(); Or more likely, about 5 passes of Split on the different delimiters you have there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a list, not an object, so you should parse like this

```
RootObject rootObject;
var matches = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<RootObject>>(json);
```

then

```
if(matches.Any())
{
    rootObject = matches[0];
}
```

And then create a method to split the history string into a list and use that, not the property

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.Net to Deserialize your response (examples [provided on this website](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingJSON.htm)) then use Split() and ToList() on your History field.

You can replace JSON.Net with JavaScriptSerializer if you don't want to use an external lib.

Comment: This is my code:
-

public Match get()
        {
            using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {

                string URL2 = @"my api url";
                var json = webClient.DownloadString(URL2);
                Match match =     JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Match>(json);
                return match;
            }
        }

This throws an error about response format

Comment: Thats is because your history property should be a string and not a list of string... the JSON you have posted is not an array of string.